# Filtering out objects with certain property value in an array (Angular)

Tags: arrays, angularjs, for-loop, filter, push

Trying to filter through an array in Angular, and filter out all objects of a certain property

I have an array like this:

```
[  
   {  
      "group":"Group A",
   },
   {  
      "group":"Group A",
   },
   {  
      "group":"Group B",
   },
   {  
      "group":"Group B",
   } 
   {  
      "group":"Group C",
   },
   {  
      "group":"Group C",
   } 
]
```

...and I want to write a function to return an array with only Group A and B (not Group C).

So far this is what I have:

```
function filterStandings() {

        for (var i = 0, len = $scope.originalArray.length; i < len; i++) {
            $scope.filteredArr = [];
            if (originalArray[i].group !== "Group C") {
                 $scope.filteredStandingsArr.push($scope.originalArray[i]);
            }
         }
         return $scope.filteredArr;
 };
```

Then I when I try to display this array in my view by calling the `filterStandings()` function, nothing shows up.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You miss a "," in your example array, after the second `{  
      "group":"Group B",
   } `

Answer (score 1):

[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro)

For your use case:

```
 $scope.filteredArr = $scope.originalArray.filter(function(item){
    return item.group !== 'Group C'
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$scope.test = function () {
    $scope.filteredArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.items[i].group != "Group C") {
             $scope.filteredArr.push($scope.items[i]);
        }
     }
     return $scope.filteredArr;
 };
```

You have just miss to use the $scope services and initialize your new array (filteredArr) in the for-loop.

You can also use the filter keyword :

JS

```
$scope.filteredArr = function (item) {
       return item.group != "Group C";
};
```

HTML

```
<div ng:repeat="item in originalArray| filter: filteredArr ">
  {{item}}
</div>
```